# Supremum of $B$, where $\sup B = \lambda + \sup A $

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

Question Setup:

Let $A$ be a set that is bounded above, where $\sup A = \lambda $
$A$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \\ $.
A set $B$ is defined as $B = \{\, x + k \ | \ x \in A, k \in \mathbb{R}\,\}$

Question:
Prove that $\sup B = \lambda + k $

My attempt:
Let $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\forall x + k \in B, \mu \geq x + k $$
i.e. $\mu$ is an upper bound of $B$
Select $\mu$ such that ,
$$\forall m \in B, m \leq \mu \implies \exists n \in B, n \geq m $$
i.e $\mu = \sup B $

We know, (everything from here on is shaky)
$$\forall x + k \in B, \mu - k \geq x $$
$$\forall x  \in A, \mu - k \geq x $$
i.e $$\mu - k \geq \sup A $$
As $ \mu = \sup B$
$$\mu - k = \sup A $$
$$\sup B = \lambda + k$$

Comment: This proof is very handwavy, want to make these more watertight, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $b\in B$, then $b=a+k$, for some $a\in A$. So, since $a\leqslant\sup A$, $b\leqslant k+\sup A$. Therefore, $k+\sup A$ is an upper bound of $B$.

And if $\mu<k+\sup A$, then $\mu-k<\sup A$. So, there is some $a\in A$ such that $a>\mu-k$, and therefore $a+k>\mu$. But $a+k\in B$. So, $\mu$ is not an upper bound of $B$. It follows that $k+\sup A$ is the *least* upper bound of $B$. In other words, $k+\sup B=\sup A$.

Comment: @RobertShore I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Took a bit of time to understand this was a proof by contradiction.
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sup B$ does not exist because $B = \mathbb{R}$, i. e., $B$ is unbunded. I think he lacks the hypothesis that B is bounded or something similar.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies in the definition of $B$, which should be $B=\{x+k\mid x\in B\}$.

Comment: Not correct.  The definition of $B$ as a translation of $A$, combined with the fact that $A$ is bounded, assures us that $B$ is bounded.

Comment: @RobertShore is easy prove that $\mathbb{R} \subset B$. If $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then take $x \in A$ and $k = y-x \in \mathbb{R}$ so $y = x+k \in B$.

Comment: Look again at the problem.  We're given that $A$ is bounded above, so $B$, which is a translation of $A$, also must be bounded above.

Comment: Oh I understood that $ k $ is fixed.